# Dart - How to sort Map's keys

Tags: dart

I have question in sorting Map's key in Dart.

```dart
Map<String, Object> map = new Map();
```

How can I sort the keys in map? or Sort the Iterable map.keys.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you want a sorted `List` of the map's keys:

```
var sortedKeys = map.keys.toList()..sort();
```

You can optionally pass a custom sort function to the `List.sort` method.

Finally, might I suggest using `Map<String, dynamic>` rather than `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: Watch out for one-liner `map.keys.toList().sort()`. In order to keep this in the same line, the cascade style should be used, as in `map.keys.toList()..sort()`.

Answer (score 97):

In Dart, it's called [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html):

```dart
import "dart:collection";

main() {
  final SplayTreeMap<String, Map<String,String>> st = 
      SplayTreeMap<String, Map<String,String>>();

  st["yyy"] = {"should be" : "3rd"};
  st["zzz"] = {"should be" : "last"};
  st["aaa"] = {"should be" : "first"};
  st["bbb"] = {"should be" : "2nd"};

  for (final String key in st.keys) {
    print("$key : ${st[key]}");
  }
}

// Output:
// aaa : first
// bbb : 2nd
// yyy : 3rd
// zzz : last
```

Comment: error with ['should be'] :  The method '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.

Comment: @Julien Which version of dart that is? Used to work in dart 1.0

Comment: dart 2, the latest

Comment: It seems to work correctly on DartPad (https://dartpad.dev/dart) as of today.

Comment: I don't understand the use case of this `SplayTreeMap` example. The original question was about sorting a `Map`'s keys; a `Map`'s values are random access, so getting a `List` of the keys and sorting it should be enough to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 13):

```
final sorted = SplayTreeMap<String,dynamic>.from(map, (a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
```

As seen at

> [How to use a SplayTreeMap on Firebase snapshot dictionary in dart/Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664718/how-to-use-a-splaytreemap-on-firebase-snapshot-dictionary-in-dart-flutter)

Answer (score 6):

I know my answer is too late but check out what I've found.. Might help someone

This [sortedmap](https://pub.dev/packages/sortedmap#-example-tab-) Package helps to maintain Map of objects in a sorted manner.

Answer (score 1):

```
map.entries.toList().sort(((a, b) => a.key.compareTo(b.key)));
```

I think so.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following code:

```
void main() {
  var x = {'b': 10, 'c': 7, 'a': 2};
  print('x = $x');
  
  final  y = x.orderByKeys(compareTo: (a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  final  z = x.orderByValues(compareTo: (a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  print('y = $y');
  print('z = $z');
  
  
}

/// Extensions on [Map] of <[K], [V]>
extension ExtendsionsOnMapDynamicDynamic<K,V> on Map<K, V>{
  /// Order by keys
  Map<K, V> orderByKeys({required int Function(K a, K b) compareTo}) {
    return Map.fromEntries(entries.toList()..sort((a, b) => compareTo(a.key, b.key)));
  }

  /// Order by values
  Map<K, V> orderByValues({required int Function(V a, V b) compareTo}) {
    return Map.fromEntries(entries.toList()..sort((a, b) => compareTo(a.value, b.value)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the map in sorted/reverse sorted order based on value as suggested below:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';
void sort() {
  var m = { 
    'A' : 3,
    'B' : 1,
    'C' : 2
  };
  var sortedKeys = m.keys.toList(growable:false)
    ..sort((k1, k2) => (m[k1] as num).compareTo(m[k2] as num));
    /* For reverse sorted order just do the below line in place of above line */
    // ..sort((k1, k2) => (m[k2] as num).compareTo(m[k1] as num));
  LinkedHashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap
      .fromIterable(sortedKeys, key: (k) => k, value: (k) => m[k]);
  print(sortedMap);
}
```